# Encapsulating material-ui into custom components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am having a bit of trouble with the `material-ui` Table component. I seperated the table logic into a header and body component and within body, added a different component for each row

```
export const PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
]

export const ProductCategoryRow = ({
  product: {
    name,
    price
    }
  }) => (<TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>
      {name}
    </TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>
      {price}
    </TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
)

const ProductHeader = () => (<TableHeader>
    <TableRow>
      <TableHeaderColumn>
        Name
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn>
        Price
      </TableHeaderColumn>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHeader>
)

export const ProductTableBody = (props) => {
  bin.log(props)
  const Products = props.products.map(product => (<ProductRow product={product} />))
  console.log(Products)
  return Products
}
```

The product table component is composed of these components:

```
//this does not work, the components are passed down to children and nothing happens.
  const ProductTable = (props) => (
    <Table>
      <ProductHeader/>
      <ProductTableBody products={props.products}/>
    </Table>
  )
```

I have a webpack bin [here](http://www.webpackbin.com/NyVO_dWsb) that you can take a look at. I have commented out the `ProductTable` that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Table>` implementation relies on its direct children having a `<TableHeader>`, a `<TableBody>`, and optionally a `<TableFooter>` component.

If it does not find at least a `<TableHeader>` and a `<TableBody>`, then it simply does not render anything in its header/body. This is what is happening in your situation.

One way you can get around this is to keep the `<TableBody>` and `<TableHeader>` with the `<Table>`, but use some helper functions to achieve a similar level of abstraction you desire.

```
const ProductCategoryRow = (props) => {
    const { name, price } = props.product

    return (
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>
              {name}
            </TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>
              {price}
            </TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    )
}


function createHeaderColumns(columnNames) {
    return columnNames.map(name => <TableHeaderColumn>{name}</TableHeaderColumn>)
}

function createTableRows(rows) {
    return rows.map(row => <ProductCategoryRow product={row} />)
}

const ProductTable = (props) => {

    const headerColumns = createHeaderColumns(props.columnNames)
    const tableRows = createTableRows(props.products)

    return (
            <Table>
                <TableHeader>
                    <TableRow>
                        {headerColumns}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableRows}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
    )
}
```